# ls should display contents of flat directory structure in columns

Tags: ls

I've got the a flat directory structure like this.

```
├── kanban
│   ├── 1_backlog
│   ├── 2_analyze
│   ├── 3_doing
│   ├── 4_test
│   ├── 5_approval
│   └── 6_done
```

Each directory contains text files while each represents a task.
A typical kanban board displays columns. I want to show the content of each directory column-wise like this.

```
1_backlog       2_analyze      ...
├── 1234_task   ├── 34235_task
├── 4567_task   ├── 32322_task
```

How is that possible?

Cheers.

Comment: Have a look at [join(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) and `ls -1`, `for f in *` or simply `find -print`. You might be able to coax them into doing what you want through an appropriate `for` loop or similar construct, although it'll probably be somewhat brittle. Pure `ls` almost certainly won't help you.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I tried with `paste`, but is does look ugly, because of variable column width from `ls -1`

Comment: @Bernhard Try playing around with `printf`. Here's a little something to get you started: `printf "Hello %20s %-20s World\n" "abc" "def"`

Comment: It's not my problem, so if it gets too complicated, there are probably better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `column` command and it supports the `-s`, `-n` and `-t` options and none of the filenames contain tab or non-printable characters.

```
cd kanban &&
  set -- */ &&
  eval "eval paste '<(tree \"\${'{1..$#}'}\")'" |  column -nts $'\t'
```

(replace `tree` with your preferred command to display a directory as a tree)

(ksh/bash/zsh syntax above).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small utility in Python that can do this:

- [Minitree](https://github.com/xyproto/minitree)

Screenshot:

[image: minitree]

Comment: +1 for turning Stephane Chazelas' 3-liner into a full-fledged Python program :)

Comment: to make it a little more compatible with the user's current environment, you could try to parse the `$COLORS` env. variable

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of customization - for example, I have a customized `~/.dir_colors`. But, upon further thought after posting my last comment, I realized that term programs have their own themes, and they don't (to my knowledge) modify any system files/env. variables - so how to match what the end-user sees with `ls` vs. `lc`? Perhaps I'll open an issue after I test it more tonight...